# ASP Razor Login Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I need help creating a login page for my site

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("database");

Validation.RequireField("Email","Required Field - Email");
Validation.RequireField("Password","Required Field - Password");

string Email = Request.Form["Email"];
string Password = Request.Form["Password"];

if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()){
    if(ModelState.IsValid){
        var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Email= @0 and Password @1";
        var result = db.Query(selectQueryString, Email, Password);
        int count = result.Count();
        if (count == 1){
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();

            foreach (var row in db.Query(result)){
                Session["FirstName"]=row.FirstName;
                Session["LastName"]=row.LastName;
                Session["Email"]=row.Email;
                Session["Telephone"]=row.telephone;
            }
            Response.Redirect("~/Home.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Invalid Username or Password</p> 
            <a href="~/"></a>
        }
    }
}}
```

On line 19 (foreach part) I get the following errors:

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'WebMatrix.Data.Database.Query(string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

I have done some digging but cant seem to find anything any ideas?

Comment: OMG, this is completely wrong. This is not php. Please read about MVC first

Comment: @nZeus, if you're going to be a punk, at least be a constructive by providing links.

Comment: You forgot the "=" sign between Password and @1.

Comment: @StevenWexler, sure, you're right. Here it is: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

Comment: This isn't MVC .. i'm sure he's working with Web pages http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: @scartag, ough.. Yes, I see, this is not about mvc. 
It's a pity that such technology exists and has relationship to ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db.Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable`.

So `result` from `var result = db.Query(selectQueryString, Email, Password)` is an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Since result is already an `IEnumerable` you don't have to call `db.Query` again.  Instead, you can iterate over results in your foreach loop.

```
foreach (var row in result) {
  Session["FirstName"]=row.FirstName;
  Session["LastName"]=row.LastName;
  Session["Email"]=row.Email;
  Session["Telephone"]=row.telephone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a total of three arguments/parameters into the Query() method:

1. the query string
2. the email
3. the password

however, the closest match only takes two parameters:

1. the query string
2. an object array of parameters

Also, I noticed that your query is vulnerable to SQL-Injection. You'll want to sanitize the inputs from the form.

Comment: To add, the reason your'e getting the "cannot convert" error message is because it sees that you are passing in Email as the second parameter to the method (which is a string). It's attempting to implicitly convert the string to an object[], which it cannot do, and is therefore erroring-out.

Comment: Also, @Exel Gamboa is correct in that you're missing syntax in your query string. Furthermore, you'll want your foreach loop to be like foreach(var row in result)